# How to get attachments in Gmail with Google Apps Script that are only attached to the messege itself

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a very simple code written for Google Apps Script that searches my email for a specific subject and  save its attachments to a folder in my drive, if found.

However, the email sometimes has another email attached to it with the extension .eml and this email attached also have its own attachments.

When I run the code it get the attachments from both emails, as if they were all in the "main" email and save them to my drive.

Is there a way of filtering these attachments, or identifying that they are not from the message so they don't get saved?

Here is the code:

```
var threads = GmailApp.search('subject:' + 'test subject');
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('someID');

if(threads.length <= 0){
    //email not found
    return "email not found";
}

for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
var messages = threads[i].getMessages();


for (var m = 0; m < messages.length; m++) {
        var msg = messages[m].getBody();

        var subject = messages[m].getSubject();

        var attachments = messages[m].getAttachments();
  
        Logger.log('attachments found ' + attachments.length);

        if (attachments.length > 0) {

    attachments.forEach(function(a){
                //create the file and limit the name to 30 characthers
        var file = folder.createFile(a.copyBlob()).setName(a.getName().substring(0,30));

    });

    
  }

  
}
```

Tried searching the documentation and looking for answers in other forums

Comment: In this question someone suggested that kind of answer. Works for me perfectly. https://stackoverflow.com/a/58168563/8642559

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## SUGGESTION

The `getAttachments()` method seems to detect attachments in **eml** files by default. However, I must emphasize that my observations lack documented support due to the absence of official references. This inference is drawn solely from my own replication.

As an alternative, I suggest utilizing the `getRawContent` method to clean the email's content data. This approach enables precise data filtering, excluding ***eml*** contents before saving attachments. For more details, refer to the adjusted script below:

***Tweaked Script***

```
function testingFunction() {
  var threads = GmailApp.search('subject:' + 'test subject');
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1uHzF0Vvr4-K4SDgprNtnwbT2VmQqeqYr');

  if (threads.length <= 0) {
    //email not found
    return "email not found";
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();


    for (var m = 0; m < messages.length; m++) {
      var msg = messages[m].getBody();
      var subject = messages[m].getSubject();
      var attachments = messages[m].getAttachments();

      //Split data by eml type or 'rfc882' to separate MAIN email attachments from the .eml file attachments
      let rawData = messages[m].getRawContent().split('rfc822');

      //Find a chunk that DO NOT contain '.eml' file attachement
      let mainEmailMessage = rawData.filter(d => !d.includes('.eml'));

      //Get the attachments from the main email message.
      let mainEmailAttachments = mainEmailMessage.map(d => d.split('Content-Disposition').filter(d => d.toLowerCase().includes('attachment') || d.includes('inline')));

      //Process main email attachements
      mainEmailAttachments.forEach(a => {
        console.log(`Source: ${subject}\n`)
        a.forEach((b, i) => {
          let filename = b.match(new RegExp('filename="(.*?)"'))[1];
          let contentType = mainEmailMessage[0].split('Content-Type').filter(d => d.includes(filename))[0].match(/: (.*?); name/)[1];
          let base64 = Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64Decode(b.match(/Content-ID:([\s\S]+?)--/)[1].split('\r\n\r\n')[1]), contentType);
          folder.createFile(base64.setName(filename));
          console.log(`Attachment #${i + 1} has been saved:\n\nFile name: ${filename}\nFile type: ${contentType}`);
        })
      });
    }
  }
}
```

***Demo***

- **A dummy email message with attachments:**
  *Contains 2 main email files (a png & a json) & 2 attached **eml*** files that also contain 1 attachment each.

> [image]

- **After running the script, here's the log for review:**

> [image]

- **The dummy drive folder:**

> [image]

### Reference

- [Gmail getRawContent()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#getrawcontent)